# End Call in Android

Tags: android, telephonymanager, phone-call

Is there any way to end the call when it is progress ? not when it enters in `CALL_STATE_RINGING/CALL_STATE_OFFHOOKstate` I want to end call when It is in   ringing/offhook  state for a while. Any solution ?

Comment: u can end the call using reflection.

Comment: Yes I have used it (ITelephony.aidl) and able to end call using telephonyService.endCall() but I want to end call when user is in between conversation on call.